# Getting string of decision variable names after optimizing in Cplex, Python

Tags: python, cplex

I would like to get the names of each decision variable after I have run my optimizing programme using Cplex in Python.

I know that there is a function in Matlab for that but I can't find it for Python.
Does anybody know if there is such a function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

let me share a small example:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

print(nbbus40.solution_value);
print(nbbus30.solution_value);

print("display")

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

which gives

```
6.0
2.0
display
nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

With the CPLEX Python API (not to be confused with the [DOcplex Modeling for Python API](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/optimization-modeling/modeling-for-python/) shown in Alex's answer), you can use the [Cplex.variables.get_names](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refpythoncplex/html/cplex._internal._subinterfaces.VariablesInterface-class.html#get_names) method. The following toy example reads a model file (given on the command line) and prints out all the names:

```
import sys
import cplex

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    raise ValueError("usage: {0} <filename>".format(sys.argv[0]))

c = cplex.Cplex(sys.argv[1])

for index, name in enumerate(c.variables.get_names()):
    print("variable[{0}] = {1}".format(index, name))
```